# Fix the width of a JTextPane in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtextpane, gridbaglayout

I have this panel:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JTable leftTable = new JTable();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.1;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        add(leftTable, gbc);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.4;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        add(textPane, gbc);

        JTable rightTable = new JTable();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        add(rightTable, gbc);
    }
}
```

Then when I enter some characters into the JTextPane it is automatically resized. With 200 characters on the same line (on the text pane), the 2 JTables are not visible anymore.

How can I do to fix the width of my JTextPane?

Thanks.

Comment: The weights in a GBL will only be used for left-over space. Unless you override the behavior, a `JTextPane` will ask for enough space to show all the text inside it - so the weights only come into account after all the text is shown. Does the layout behave decently if the `JTable`s have contents, too? How do you want the layout to behave? You could use `setPreferredSize` on the JTextPane to 'fix' the size, but that should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used a [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) from [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/).

```
private void initItemsPanel() {
    JPanel itemsPanel = new JPanel();
    itemsPanel.setLayout(new FormLayout("left:pref, fill:400px, pref:grow", "fill:20px, fill:4px, fill:max(20px;pref)"));
    CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();

    // the left table
    JTable leftTable = new JTable();
    itemsPanel.add(leftTable.getTableHeader(), cc.xywh(1, 1, 1, 2));
    itemsPanel.add(leftTable, cc.xywh(1, 3, 1, 1));

    // the text pane
    itemsPanel.add(new JTextPane(), cc.xywh(2, 2, 1, 2));

    // the right table
    JTable rightTable = new JTable();
    rightTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
    itemsPanel.add(rightTable.getTableHeader(), cc.xywh(3, 1, 1, 2));
    itemsPanel.add(rightTable, cc.xywh(3, 3, 1, 1));

    // Adding the items panel to dialog panel
    JScrollPane itemsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(itemsPanel);
    itemsScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(3);

    dialogPanel.add(itemsScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); // with dialogPanel previously instantiated
}
```

For all the situations I tested (resizing, empty/filled components, etc.) it was more predictable.

Note that you have to call `getTableHeader()` explicitly because the JTables are not directly in a JScrollPane.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know you sorted it out somehow +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;` for the JTextPane

Comment: @StanislavL Did that: `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL; gbc.weightx = 0.0;` but my JTextPane is still resized when I type in. And I still don't know how to fix its width.

Comment: @MarcdeVerdelhan : Do one thing then, add your `JTextPane` to `JScrollPane` and put this `JScrollPane` along with `JTable`.

Comment: Erf. I can't do that. MyPanel is already in a JScrollPane component. I want these 3 components (the 2 jtables and the jscrollpane) to be synchronized so I can't use an independant one for the JTextPane.

Comment: May you provide some sort of a code snippet, as to how you planning to go about it ? That might be of some help. What if, instead of using **GridBagLayout** you use **GridLayout** and put the three inside the `JScrollPane` ? Won't that be of any help, since all three will take same dimensions ?